# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to undo a delete operation through the action provided by `Snackbar`.

Here is the **delete** operation:

```
dbRef.child(footballer.getFullName()).removeValue();
```

When I call the **undo** operation through the command added below, getting `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class` exception:

```
dbRef.setValue(footballer.getFullName(), footballer);
```

`dbRef` is assigned to the root of the collection:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("footballers");
```

Here is my `Footballer` model:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Footballer {

    private String fullName;
    private String desc;
    private String photoUrl;
    private String teamUrl;

    public Footballer() {
    }

    public Footballer(String fullName, String desc, String photoUrl, String teamUrl) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.teamUrl = teamUrl;
    }
    // getter-setter methods
}
```

Here is the structure of Firebase database:

```
footballers
----Cristiano Ronaldo
--------fullName
--------desc
--------photoUrl
--------teamUrl
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tk"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    // Support Design Lib
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    // Swipe Action
    compile 'co.dift.ui.swipetoaction:library:1.1'
    // Facebook Fresco
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add you more code and the database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo More detail is added to the original post, Alex.

Comment: I see. Please also add your build.gradle file.

Comment: @AlexMamo updated, Alex. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: thats because you are trying to read a file that is not there, a good suggestion will be to store your data into a sharedpreferences, so when you delete it it will be saved like a recycler bin in your shared preferences, so when you press undo you just bring the data from the preferences and in the background you upload it again to firebase, so the data will be placed at the same spot in the database at it was deleted

Comment: Have you tried to use this line of code: `dbRef.child(footballer.getFullName()).setValue(footballer);`?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Not an optimum solution Gaston to keep the data which is already stored on Firebase. Thanks Alex, worked like a charm.

Comment: not keeping it, if you gonna delete it, you should save it anywhere if the user wanna undo it

Comment: The data is already stored in the Adapter, Gaston. Thanks for your comment which is appreciated. @GastónSaillén